# Django 2.0 ipn callback => Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set) despite @csrf_exempt

Tags: django, django-csrf

I use Django 2.0 and I want to accept an IPN from a remote third-party on my url http://example.com/ipn/

This is my url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
# url for ipn
    url(r'^ipn/$', views.index, name='ipn'),
    ...
]
```

This is my view:

```
# decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def ipn(request):
    ''' process ipn call from merchant'''
    ipn = get_data_from_ipn(request)
```

in my settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ipnsender.net']
...
```

I'd like that only the ipn view does not use csrf, but I can not understand why I do have the following error although the documentation only tells you need @csrf_exempt decorator.

My log tells me every time:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /ipn/
[13/Mar/2018 22:36:50] "POST /ipn/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2868
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `index` and not `ipn` function inside `urls.py` for handling `/ipn/`

`url(r'^ipn/$', views.ipn, name='ipn'),`

Comment: Thanks a lot, was right under my nose but could not find it. I'd like to upvote but I don't have enough karma yet.